# What to use to get full screen element in twitter bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've just started to learn the responsive framework `Bootstrap` and I'm trying to figure out how to make a full width element for the whole screen.

Like, I was reading an article and it pointed out that normally you would use `.container` as this centers things on the screen and adds padding on the edges; it then went on to say that you should use `.container-fluid` if you want it to go full screen as it is set to a width of `100%`.

I have downloaded `Bootstrap 3.20` and that is not true, they are exactly the same:

CSS:

```
.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.container-fluid {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

So, if I am wanting to use a full screen method, what do I use for the container?

Comment: Why don't you try it out and see what it does?

Comment: @DavidG Ummmmm....... I did; as per my question and per the code, it does exactly the same thing.

Comment: Then you did something wrong. As koala_dev explained, the fluid container isn't limited and used full width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is in the media queries they use to set the size of `.container`:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 750px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 970px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}
```

`.container-fluid` is always 100% so in your case you'd want to use that or depending on the scenario you may just use a plain `<div>`

Comment: Ok, but `container-fluid` still has the padding on the edges and hence it doesn't go full screen.

Comment: @Brett if you want a "true" full-width element just use a div without any container class, a `.container-fluid` is to be combined with a `.row` which has negative margins to compensate the padding